# What is wrong with this axios async/await request for React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, promise, axios

I'm trying to implement async/await promise with axios. The first request is being completed and then property populated with the response. However I can't get to assign with the second request the response as a property to each item of the array generated with the first request:

```
async componentDidMount(){
 await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
    this.setState({geoLat:position.coords.latitude,geoLng:position.coords.longitude});
    axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&radius=5000&keyword=recensioni&type=restaurant&types=restaurant&key=AIzaSyCZ7rgMN34kWkGvr8Pzkf_8nkT7W6gowBA`)
         .then(response =>this.setState({restaurantsFetchedFromGoogle:response.data.results}));
    });

    this.setState({restaurantsFetchedFromGoogle:this.state.restaurantsFetchedFromGoogle.map(item=>{
      axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${item.place_id}&key=AIzaSyCZ7rgMN34kWkGvr8Pzkf_8nkT7W6gowBA`).then(response=>
      ...item,
      reviews:response.data.reviews
      )
    })
  }
```

the `item` already has some properties from the first axios call and I'm trying to spread them with `...item` and just add on top of that the `reviews:response.data.reviews` as a key-value pair in the item object. What am I doing wrong with the second return of the axios response?

Comment: `await` doesn't help if you're not using promises but still passing callbacks

Comment: First `async/await` only works with promises. You can't use it like this `await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback)`

Comment: Also this part `axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${item.place_id}&key=AIzaSyCZ7rgMN34kWkGvr8Pzkf_8nkT7W6gowBA`).then(response=>
          ...item,
          reviews:response.data.reviews
          )` is invalid.

Comment: So if'd remove async/await, how would the response body of the second axios request be? how would I add the property reviews with it's response from the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is asynchronous, with that said, and if i understood correctly, you are doing it one after the other setState. What is problably happening is that when the first setState is being populated the second one happens too and you lose the content from the first setState.

You can run the second setState only after the first one is done like so:

```
axios.get(stuff).then(stuff => {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    geoLat: stuff
  }, () => {
    // run after stuff is in state
    axios.get(stuff).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        restaurantsFetchedFromGoogle: response
      }, () => {
        // continue with the next axios request and setState
      })
    })
  })
})
```